# How can I increment array with loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I've got two lists:

```
listOne = ['33.325556', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']
listTwo = ['2.5929778', '1.57945488999', '8.57262235411']
```

I use len to tell me how many items are in my list:

```
itemsInListOne = int(len(listOne))
itemsInListTwo = int(len(listTwo))
```

Then, this is where I get stuck. I want to loop through the list using a while loop and increment the array with each loop. Here is what I tried:

```
iterations = 0

while iterations < itemsInListOne:
        listOne = listOne[0] + 1
        print iterations
```

The while loop is clearly wrong, but you can see what i'm trying to do. I want to end up with:

```
listOne[0]
listOne[1]
listOne[2]
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To better explain this.

I've got a list and I want to loop through the list and automatically create an array which increments with each iteration, for example:

```
listOne[0] 
+1
listOne[1] 
+ 1 
listOne[2]
```

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: What does this have to do with `listTwo`?

Comment: What do you mean by "increment the array with each loop"?

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but what you're trying to achieve doesn't seem really clear. Can't you give us the real output of what you want ?

Comment: Explosion Pills - I want to do the same thing with list two. I'll edit my post. Warunsl - I mean I want my script to automatically make the variable listOne[0] then listOne[1] right the way up until it reaches the end of the list. I need to use the information in the array later on in my script.

Comment: Added further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to do:

```
while iterations < itemsInListOne:
    listOne[iterations] = float(listOne[iterations]) + 1
```

Note that you needed to convert it to a `float` before adding to it.

Also note that this could be done more easily with a list comprehension:

```
listOne = [float(x) + 1 for x in listOne]
```

Answer (score 0):

since you can't increment a `list` (it's technically not an array), I assume you want to increment each list element. If this is the case you might want something like this:

```
iterations = 0

while iterations < itemsInListOne:
    listOne[iterations] += 1
    print iterations
    iterations += 1
```

I hope I understood you right, if not so, please consider rewriting your question, to make it clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# You could do it in one line using list comprehension in Python
def loop_and_increment(data):                                                   
    return [ str(float(_) + 1) for _ in data]                                   

print loop_and_increment(listOne)                                               
print loop_and_increment(listTwo)
```