# How can I use string formatting to assign unique variable?

Tags: python, string, loops, formatting

I've got a list and i've managed to turn the list into strings. Now I want to assign a variable to each item in the list by using string formatting to append a 1 onto the end of the variable.

```
listOne = ['33.325556', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']

itemsInListOne = int(len(listOne))

num = 4
varIncrement = 0

while itemsInListOne < num:
    for i in listOne:
        print a = ('%dfinalCoords{0}') % (varIncrement+1)
        print (str(listOne).strip('[]'))
    break
```

I get the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I fix this and assign a new variable in the format:

a0 = 33.325556
a1 = 59.8149016457 etc.

Comment: That is not a good idea.  Instead, make `a` a dictionary or list and put your values in that structure.

Comment: I know it's not ideal but I need to assign a unique variable for each string asap

Comment: I doubt it.  Can you explain why you think you need to access the values as `a0`, `a1`, etc., instead of `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Because my script is ripping coordinates from photographs. The user selects X number of photographs, rips out the coordinates into a list. I don't know how many photographs they are going to select, it could be 30, could be 100. I need a way of AUTOMATICALLY assigning each coordinate a variable. This is the only way I can think of doing it. I'm tearing my hair out trying to think of a way. If you know better, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: @BrenBarn is right, you should just put them in a list

Comment: You could use `exec` if you really wanted to (e.g., `exec('a%d = value')`), but I have to second @BrenBarn: this is not a good idea.

Comment: I was told in a previous post that I cannot auto-increment an array. So does anyone have any better ideas on what I can do?

Comment: attaching the value to variable name is not a good idea. Instead, you could create dictionary of list. For ex, if user selects 110 photos, then you can have structure as {'photo1':[x_coord,y_coord],...,'photo100':[x_coord,y_coord]}. This way you access photo1's co-ord as d['photo1'][0] ==> x_coord and d['photo1'][1] ==> y_coord

Comment: @BubbleMonster I don't know what "auto-increment an array" means, but you can easily iterate through Python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code has a few issues:

```
listOne = ['33.325556', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']

itemsInListOne = int(len(listOne)) # len will always be an int

num = 4 # magic number - why 4?
varIncrement = 0

while itemsInListOne < num: # why test, given the break?
    for i in listOne:
        print a = ('%dfinalCoords{0}') % (varIncrement+1) # see below
        print (str(listOne).strip('[]')) # prints list once for each item in list
    break # why break on first iteration
```

One line in particular is giving you trouble:

```
print a = ('%dfinalCoords{0}') % (varIncrement+1)
```

This:

1. simultaneously tries to `print` and assign `a =` (hence the `SyntaxError`);
2. mixes two different types of string formatting (`'%d'` and `'{0}'`); and
3. never actually increments `varIncrement`, so you will always get `'1finalCoords{0}'` anyway.

I would suggest the following:

```
listOne = ['33.325556', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']

a = list(map(float, listOne)) # convert to actual floats
```

You can easily access or edit individual values by index, e.g.

```
# edit one value
a[0] = 33.34

# print all values
for coord in a:
    print(coord)

# double every value
for index, coord in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = coord * 2
```

---

Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075824/how-can-i-increment-array-with-loop), it seems that you probably want pairs of coordinates from two lists, which can also be done with a simple list of 2-tuples:

```
listOne = ['33.325556', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']
listTwo = ['2.5929778', '1.57945488999', '8.57262235411']

coord_pairs = zip(map(float, listOne), map(float, listTwo))
```

Which gives:

```
coord_pairs == [(33.325556, 2.5929778), 
                (59.8149016457, 1.57945488999), 
                (51.1289412359, 8.57262235411)]
```